# Get previous input on sqlite CLI tool

Tags: sqlite, command-line-interface

I'd like to access my previous inputs on the sqlite CLI tool. In bash it works with the arrow up-key but in after running `sqlite3` and pressing that key I'm just getting `^[[A`. How can I fix this? Which key lets me use my previous typed commands?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sqlite3 binary was not built with support for readline.

Either get one that does. Or you can wrap it with readline via rlwrap.

```
rlwrap sqlite3
```

Comment: Thank you very much! But please note that `rlwrap` is not installed by default (at least for me on Ubuntu 18) and needs to be installed first :)